# How can you have a skeptics blog when people delete answers they do not agree with for political or religious reasons

Tags: discussion, deletion

I recently answered a question relating to events during WW2. My answer was based on extensive research I and others have done into post war claims and accusations made against the Germans which were accepted as factual at the time. Since then much research has been made into those claims and has found them to be unsubstantiated and with no solid evidence to back them up.
Since then a huge effort has been made by those supporting those claims to suppress public discussion and debate on them and to persecute those who have published their research. My answer was based on that research and my own but was deleted for obvious reasons. How can you run a skeptics section on a questions and answers site that allow people to suppress factually based well researched answers by deleting those which they do not agree with?

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't a blog. Political *opinions* of all persuasions are unwelcome. A common mistake is that people come here thinking "skeptics" means denialist or contrarian; that is not the way we use the word.

Answer (score 10):

On this questions and answers site we expect all answers to provide links or pointers to solid, verifiable evidence -- especially if your answer goes against commonly accepted history.

In particular, Nazi revisionism is (for all I know) anti-historical, and hence completely inappropriate here. I might be wrong, though.

If so, edit your answer, provide reference from respectable historians and "flag it" or comment on it so it can be reinstated by a mod.

Please in the future don't assume that moderators here do their job based on political bias. I've been accused in the past of being liberal, conservative, nazi, communist, etc. It isn't nice.

Comment: As i am sure you well know, every scholar and scientist who has dared to stand up and publish revisionist research has been persecuted to hell and back, character assassinated and even put on trial. It was that which led me to do my own research and what I found was a huge conspiracy to suppress the information that backs up the revisionist case because the lie that was told had such repercussions for the rest of the 20th century. Their problem is the lie was so weak it can not stand up to modern scrutiny so they go to extreme lengths to try and prevent public debate or discussion.

Comment: @Scarecrow, you did your own research? Great, you probably based that research on evidence and sources. Please, edit your answer and include your sources. So that we can all see them and be convinced that you are correct. Otherwise all we have is an anonimous person on the internet telling us to trust them, and that they have done the research, but are unwilling to present it to us, which is not very convincing.

Comment: @IlyaMelamed original research is likely not valid

Comment: @sklivvz, I assume that by "doing reserch" he ment reading existing sources. If by research he ment that he interviewed witnesses and did outopcies, then it's indeed not valid, then he should publish his results, allow it to be peer reviwed and then to use the published, peer reviwed source to answer the question.

Comment: Ohhh well silly me you should have said that in the first place, I did not realize in order for an answer not to be deleted the responder must convince the select few (you) that their answer is correct. Well I better not hold you up, you all have lots of deleting to do, I'm sure there are thousands of answers on this site that will also not convince you they are correct.

Comment: If you want confirmation on whether nazi revisionism is scientifically supportable in historiography context, may be worth posting that as a question on History.SE to generate a definitive reference

Comment: @scarecrow Just write a well sourced answer. There are plenty of revisionist prestigious scientists and historians out there with some very well done papers. Even if they fell from grace after publishing their work.

Answer (score 2):

You say that:

> People delete answers they do not agree with for **political or religious reasons**.

Then going on saying that:

> My answer was based on that research and my own but was deleted for **obvious** reasons.

You are claiming that moderators delete posts because they go against their religion and political affiliation. That is absolutely wrong and I have never actually seen this type of behavior from any moderator (or even members) from Skeptics Stack Exchange.

Instead of arguing against the deletion of you answer and show that the evidence you provided in your answer is valid, you go on with "false accusations".

I hope that you realize that "[false accusations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_accusation)" (or groundless accusations or unfounded accusations or false allegations or false claims)  will make your argument weaker. Also, you should realize that all moderators here are **well bred**.

**Conclusion:** With all respect, your claim is ridiculous: deserving or inviting derision or mockery; absurd.